# How to set a cookie properly in AngleSharp?

Tags: c#, web-scraping, cookies, anglesharp

I'm writing an app to automate grabbing data from my profile on the website Criticker.com. I'm able to successfully log into the website with AngleSharp, and after I do so, I grab the cookie, but when I try to reuse it later, it doesn't seem to work.

After I sign in to the site, I grab the cookie using:

`Cookie = document.Cookie;`

which I then save in a file to retrieve the next time I load the app

So when connecting to the site next time, I use this code:

```
context = BrowsingContext.New(AngleSharp.Configuration.Default.WithDefaultLoader().WithJs().WithDefaultCookies());

if (Cookie is not null)
    context.SetCookie(new Url("https://www.criticker.com"), Cookie);


var document = await context.OpenAsync("https://www.criticker.com");
```

However, when I check, I can tell I'm not still signed in, even though when I use the site on chrome, I stay signed in for a month.

When the document loads, I do see the cookie listed in document.Cookie, so it seems like setting it worked, but why isn't it logged in then when the page loads?

Answer (score 0):

For cookies I'd recommend to use `AngleSharp.Io`. This has a much better implementation for cookies - the core AngleSharp library just has a wrapper around the .NET cookie store, which, unfortunately is not good.

After installing AngleSharp.Io (https://github.com/AngleSharp/AngleSharp.Io) you can create your config like

```
var config = AngleSharp.Configuration.Default.WithDefaultLoader().WithJs().WithTemporaryCookies();
```

Make sure that the cookie value also has a `Path=/` / the full value usually returned from the `Set-Cookie` response header.

Comment: I do have AngleSharp.Io installed, so it looks like the only real difference would be WithTemporaryCookies() instead of WithDefaultCookies()?

Would that really make a difference? 

The cookie I'm getting currently doesn't have Path=/

Comment: Yes it does - `WithDefaultCookies` comes from AngleSharp (as explained) and the other one is one of the many ways to integrate the AngleSharp.Io cookie manager.

Comment: I tried it but when using WithTemporaryCookies() I wasn't able to log into the page anymore.